# Its giving blank result after parsing the pdf containing unicode strings using php codeigniter and pdf2text

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my controller function where i am extracting the pdf2text with class and storing it in database, as this function is not displaying any result it is giving blank page in the browser.

```
public function extract_text_trial()
        {
                    $path=base_url("upload/".$file);                
                    $a = new PDF2Text();
                    $a->setFilename($path); 
                    $a->decodePDF();
                    $s=$a->output();

                    $n=stristr($s,'District:');
                    $n1 = explode("\n",$n);
                    $Dist= $n1[0];
                    print "$Dist";

                    $n=stristr($s,'Type of Information:');
                    $n1 = explode("\n", $n);
                    $TOI= $n1[0];
                    print "$TOI";

                    $this->load->model('Uploadm');
            //store the extracted texts in the database
                    $data =$this->Uploadm-  >save_fir($District,$TypeofInformation);
                    $data['query']=$this->Uploadm->view_data();
                    $this->load->view('Uploadview',$data);
            }
```

Comment: what you are getting in *$data* ?

Comment: Syntax error? "$data =$this->Uploadm-  >save_fir", there should not be a space there.

Comment: Their is no syntax error and their is no space in that. In $data i am storing the contents of the pdf what i am extracting out of it. The output is blank it is not displaying any result.

Comment: @Amruta firstly let me know where have you place `PDF2Text()` this class?. Also as mittul said check the value of `$data` before passing it to view

Comment: @Nishant PDF2Text() is my class and I have placed it in the controller itself and I am including it as include_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/classpdf2text.php"); and when i am checking the value as var_dump($s) I am getting this value string(0) "".